# NHibernate: Fetch an association which exists only in a subclass of the Query<>'d type

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I've got a table-per-subclass setup using NHibernate & I'm trying to construct a LINQ query which pre-fetches certain properties that can exist in the derived classes, but I just can't work out how to write the query. E.g. Something like:

```
var elements = session.Query<Element>()
        .Fetch(e => e.Design) // Fine, resides in Element
      //.Fetch(e => (e as Material)?.Category)
      //.Fetch(e => (e as Operational)?.EnergySource)
        .Where(e => elementIdList.Contains(e.Id)) // Or similar query
```

Obviously the above won't work; I need a statement that can actually be converted to SQL -- How can I explicitly instruct NHibernate to fetch a derived class' associations? I.e. Assume in the following classes that `Design`, `Category` and `EnergySource` have `<many-to-one>` relationships from their corresponding "Elements"

```
public class Element
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Design Design { get; set; }
}

public class Material : Element
{
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Operational : Element
{
    public virtual EnergySource EnergySource { get; set; }
}
```

I can emulate it using `ToFuture` queries on both subclasses & then merging the results, or with an appropriate default config + `QueryOver<>`, but trying to work out how to do this with `Query<>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use explicit cast to subclass:

```
var query = session.Query<Element>()
      .Fetch(e => ((Material)e).Category)
      .Fetch(e => ((Operational)e).EnergySource);
//Same applies to Where clause
    .Where( e => ((Material)e).SomeMaterialValue > 10);
```

Note: NHibernate detects subclasses by property name (actual cast type is not used so the following `.Fetch(e => ((UnrelatedClass)e).Category))` will also fetch `Material.Category`). It also means that if you have the same property name in different subclasses NHibernate won't be able to properly detect correct subclass.

Comment: Adding in `.Fetch(x => ((Material)x).Category)` I get the error, "ArgumentException: A fetch request must be a simple member access expression of the kind o => o.Related; 'Convert(x).Category' is too complex." -- I am using a pretty old version of NHibernate.

Comment: It works with 5.3...